# How to loop delay 1 second "inside Console of Google Chrome"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want to run `myCustomFunction` **inside "Console of Google Chrome" with 1 second delay on each loop**.

Tried `setInterval` but no avail as no execution delay was observed inside Console of Google Chrome.

```
const  myCustomFunction = i => console.log('iteration test number', i);
for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    setInterval(myCustomFunction(i), 1000);
};
```

1. I expect Google Chrome's Console to delay 1 second (or more) for each iteration before running `myCustomFunction`.
2. I need this to work **inside the Console of Google Chrome**, not module in 'fileName.js'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a delay in a JavaScript loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code to give expected output.

```js
const  myCustomFunction = i => console.log('iteration test number', i);
for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    setTimeout(myCustomFunction, 1000 * i, i);
}
```

Let us discuss changes,

1. Replaced `setInterval` with `setTimeout`: `setInterval` executes given function on an given interval. So, if you called `setInterval(myCustomFunction, 1000)`, it will repeatedly execute `myCustomFunction` after every 1s. This is not the behavior you want, you only want a delay of 1s and for that `setTimeout` is more appropriate.
2. first argument of `setInterval`/`setTimeout` is a function, but output of `myCustomFunction(i)` was `undefined`. So, instead of calling `myCustomFunction` there just pass it.
3. Changed delay from `1000` to `i*1000`: As contents of for loop executes without any delay. So, change delay to execute `myCustomFunction` after `i seconds`.
4. 3rd parameter of `setTimeout` `i`: `setTimeout` passes all parameters after 2nd(delay) to callback function(in our case `myCustomFunction`).

For reference visit

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/ro/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Answer (score 0):

You can do as following, using setInterval as main function instead of loop.

```
const  myCustomFunction = i => console.log('iteration test number', i);
let iteration = 0;
const delay = 1000;
const tillCount = 11;

setInterval(() => {
    if (iteration < tillCount) {
      iteration ++;
      myCustomFunction(iteration);
    }
}, delay);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to **use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) to execute your function** *(as many times you set)* **and stop it with [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval)**. Otherwise, your setInterval will keep running forever.

```js
const customFunction = i => console.log('Iteration:', i);
let counter = 0;
const maxIteration = 5;
const delay = 1000;

const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    if (counter < maxIteration) {
      counter++;
      customFunction(counter);
    } else {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
}, delay);
```

Answer (score 0):

Se the code below and read the comment to understand

```js
const  myCustomFunction = i => console.log('iteration test number', i);
repeat = 10; // how many time to repeat;
var i =0; // value to increase.
function loop(){
myCustomFunction(i); 
i++;
if (i<= repeat) // if the loop is suppose to continue
    setTimeout(loop, 1000); // wait 1s and loop agen
}

loop();
```